# Generate a random number between a min and max in BigQuery

Tags: sql, random, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use BigQuery to generate a random number between 40,000 and 50,957. But I have no idea how to do this; in Snowflake I'd use something like:

```sql
select uniform(40000, 50957, random())
```

But in BigQuery, the `RAND()` function only generates a random number between 0 and 1. How would I turn this into something that is between 40,000 and 50,957? I'm sure it is probably a matter of figuring out the maths but I failed that in high school so ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to further refactor your findings (BigQuery Standard SQL) by using UDF

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION uniform(min_value INT64, max_value INT64, value FLOAT64) AS (
  CAST(ROUND(min_value + value * (max_value - min_value)) AS INT64)
);
SELECT uniform(40000, 50957, RAND())
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! was just a matter of finding the [right website](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-math-functions/sql-rand/). Here is how to do it in just SQL without creating a temporary function:

```sql
select cast(ROUND(40000 + RAND() * (50957 - 40000)) as INT64)
```